# using partial view and link asp.net mvc 3, seems to be returning query result from another controller

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a controller to return businesses in a certain categorey

```
 public ViewResult Browse(int? id)
 {

     var companyquery = from c in db.Advertises
                        where c.CategoryID == id && c.showentry
                        select c;


        return View(companyquery);


    }
```

When a user click into a categorey the first three listings are 'Priority' listings. I have created three bools in my model for Priority 1,2 and 3. I have written the following three controllers, which return partial views to get these results;

```
 public ActionResult P1()
    {
        var presult1 = from ap in db.Advertises
                       where ap.priority1
                       select ap;

        return View(presult1);
    }



    public ActionResult P2()
    {
        var presult2 = from bp in db.Advertises
                       where bp.priority2 && bp.showentry == true
                       select bp;

        return View(presult2);
    }



    public ActionResult P3()
    {
        var presult3 = from cp in db.Advertises
                       where cp.priority3
                       select cp;

        return View(presult3);
    }
```

These partial views are included on my 'Browse' (see first controller) view like so;

```
<div id="pri1">


@Html.Partial("P1")

</div>

<div id="pri2">

@Html.Partial("P2")

</div>

<div id="pri3">

@Html.Partial("P3")

</div>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{

<div class="company">

     <div class="compimg">
         <img src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageUrl) alt ="pic"  />
            </div>
      <div class="compname">
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.companyname)
            </div>
         <ul class="social......
```

I expected this to include the priority listings at the top of the page and the  normal   listing below it. Instead these three controllers return the same results. Here is the relevant parts of my model;

```
 [DisplayName("Priority 1 listing?")]
    public bool priority1 { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Priority 2 listing?")]
    public bool priority2 { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Priority 3 listing?")]
    public bool priority3 { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Display Listing?")]
    public bool showentry { get; set; }
```

What am I misssing here? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is the seperate controller and full view which returns fine;

```
    public class P1Controller : Controller
{

    private DataContext db = new DataContext();
    //
    // GET: /P1/

    public ActionResult P1()
    {
        var presult1 = from ap in db.Advertises
                       where ap.priority1
                       select ap;

        return View(presult1);
    }

}
```

}

```
@model IEnumerable<NewAtAClick.Models.Advertise>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "P1";
 }
```

### P1

```
 <p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
 </p>
 <table>
<tr>
    <th>
        CategoryID
    </th>
    <th>
        AdName
    </th>
    <th>
        phone
    </th>
    <th>
        prefcontact
    </th>
    <th>
        phonecontact
    </th>
    <th>
        priority1
    </th>
    <th>
        priority2
    </th>
    <th>
        priority3
    </th>
    <th>
        showentry
    </th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>

     @foreach (var item in Model) {
   <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phone)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.prefcontact)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phonecontact)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.priority1)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.priority2)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.priority3)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.showentry)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AdvertiseID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.AdvertiseID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.AdvertiseID })
    </td>
   </tr>
```

}

```
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
@Html.Partial("P1")
```

try:

```
@Html.Action("P1")
```

And so on for `P2` and `P3`. This way you will be actually invoking the corresponding controller actions. For more information about the `Html.Action` helper you make take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx). Also to avoid any recursive problems make sure that in the 3 controller actions you are returning a `PartialView` instead of a `View` or inside the `P1.cshtml` partial set `Layout = null`.

Comment: Hello again Darin. I already had tried @Html.Action, but I was returning View instead of PartialView. Thanks for your help, if I'm ever in Sofia I'm buying you a truck full of beer!

Comment: @Dan, glad I could help. I am currently on vacation and enjoying plenty of beer :-)

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things, you're not actually calling the actions for `P1`, `P2`, and `P3`, you're just rending the partial views with that same name.

Have you confirmed that whatever you are doing in the partial views for each is correct?

Comment: Yes, I have created a full view for P1 and tested it. It returns the entries fine, only the ones with priority1 checked.

Comment: Can you add that to your question?